# printf and (signed) int of unknown size

Tags: c, printf, typedef

I have a platform dependent type defined in my code:
`typedef uint64_t myType;`

However on some more limited platform, it might be 32 bits.

How do I `printf` it?
As in, in the current situation, I can use `%llu`, but if on another platform it's 32 bits, this is not the best idea.

I thought about using some macros, but would anyone know of a better way? I'd love to hear about some format specifier that could take the length from the next argument, for example.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question. If on some platforms it will be 32-bit, and you know it is running on those platforms, do you need a 64-bit number?

Comment: Define a printf format specifier macro along with your typedef

Comment: Also, choose a single language tag according to what language you are using

Comment: In C++? Easy, just `cout << whatever;`.

Comment: I saw someone's comment as the answer -- I think they are making a proper answer -- http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer

Comment: In C, use the same approach as C does for `uint64_t` and `uint32_t` themselves: define macros `#define PRIdMyType PRId64`/`#define PRIdMyType PRId32` etc. In C++, don't use `printf`.

Comment: Shame on me, as @R noticed, the title says signed... it's actually unsigned. But I probably doesn't really matter anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have platform-specific *types,* it should be easy enough to use platform-specific *format strings* as well, something like:

```
#ifdef USING_64_bits
    typedef uint64_t myType;
    #define MY_TYPE_FMT PRIu64
#else
    typedef uint32_t myType;
    #define MY_TYPE_FMT PRIu32
#endif
```

Then you can use it with:

```
myType var1 = 42, var2 = 99;
printf ("%6" MY_TYPE_FMT ", %019" MY_TYPE_FMT "\n", var1, var2);
```

The extraction of the `%` from the format string allows you to insert other format specifiers dynamically, such as field widths and padding characters.

You'll also notice that I've avoided the `%llu`-style format specifiers, you should be using the more targeted ones in `inttypes.h` since the implementation will give you the correct one for your type.

Comment: Or remove the "%" so you can add other flags when calling printf.

Comment: Accepting this one on the count that it actually also answers a broader question of printing platform dependent types.

Answer (score 5):

Just cast it up to the largest-possible integer type matching the desired signedness and use the format for that, either:

```
printf("%jd", (intmax_t)x);
```

or:

```
printf("%ju", (uintmax_t)x);
```

(The question title asks for signed but the body is using unsigned examples, so I've covered both.)

This is a lot less ugly/more readable than using the `PRI*` macros suggested in the other answer, and also works for types where you don't inherently know the right `PRI` macro to use, like `off_t`.

Comment: I think it should be `uintmax_t`

Comment: The question title says signed but the body says unsigned. I'll clarify.